# Repeating badges over multiple sites

Tags: feature-request, badges

I'm active over several sites and I'm receiving the 'Editor' badge (for instance) over and over again. Now, I'm not against receiving badges, but I proposo to award these in the background, instead of showing the top banner. It's no big deal to Edit a question once you've done it for the very first time. Editing a first question on three, four or more StackExchange sites does not amount to much.

This goes for basic badges. It feels great to receive a 'recognition' badge, no matter what site you are on, and see the top banner with a merit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To a new user, who's never seen the badge system, these notifications can be very dramatic (and gratifying).  After the first two or three badges, the remaining ones are harder to earn, so you don't see this banner anymore unless you do something significant to earn a badge.

I can see why you wouldn't want to see the "newbie" badges over and over when you join new sites on the SE network.  But in a very real sense you are a newbie on those sites; the faq (and the rules) are different for each one, especially with respect to the on-topic nature of the subject matter.

All other things being equal, I prefer consistent behavior across all sites over the additional complexity of suppressing badge notifications you've already seen before.

Comment: I see what you mean and it's just a minor annoyance. However, the consistency of showing these badges is not something to aim for. Everything else being equal, SE is a community of sites and therefor needs some inter-community behavior.

Comment: A better solution would be to only award newbie badges once, on the first site.

Comment: Definitely. The idea did cross my mind :)